# Understanding Avot D'Rav Natan 33:2 regarding spliting of the Sea of Reeds

Tags: midrash, beshalach, avot-derabbi-natan

I'm trying to reconcile [Avot D'Rav Natan 33:2's](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/avot/33-2.htm) description of what occurred on the bank of the Sea of Reeds. He seems to indicate that Moshe had to coax B'nai Yisra'el to enter the sea. Each time, they demanded that another form of miracle should occur until they would go.

I understand the first few - they wanted to see the see split into separate lanes, they wanted to see dry land, etc. But, in viewing this description, something puzzles me. I know that in [Shemot 14:11-12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=198&hilite=) they say that it would be better to remain in Egypt than dying in the desert. Then, Moses assure them that G-d will fight for them, and they should just stand, see and be silent.

Fine, I get the idea that even that speech doesn't reassure most of them, and they're still doubting Moses's leadership and, probably G-d's abilities to perform miracles and save them. But, now that they see that Moses split the sea, and the land is dry, why do they keep insisting on additional miracles as described by Avot D'Rav Nattan? He describes their insistence on 10 different miracles before they actually passed through the sea. If their faith was so weak, what was it about the last one mentioned (there were like "skins" in the water that fed the babies oil and honey.) that convinced them?

(I realize that Avot Derav Nattan is describing some Midrash (I don't know his source). But, it still leaves the questions I asked. Or, Avot Derav Nattan is trying to teach us something else that's significant about why they required so many different miracles.)